# Is there a difference between new Class[]{} and new Class[0]?

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a difference between `new Class[]{}` and `new Class[0]`? If yes, what is different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No difference.

Decompiling this:

```
final class Foo {
  Class[] a = new Class[]{};
  Class[] b = new Class[0];
}
```

yields

```
final class Foo {
  java.lang.Class[] a;

  java.lang.Class[] b;

  Foo();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: iconst_0
       6: anewarray     #2                  // class java/lang/Class
       9: putfield      #3                  // Field a:[Ljava/lang/Class;
      12: aload_0
      13: iconst_0
      14: anewarray     #2                  // class java/lang/Class
      17: putfield      #4                  // Field b:[Ljava/lang/Class;
      20: return
}
```

That is, the two forms yield identical bytecode.